# WHEN condition in MySql genrating multiple column instead of one?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case-when

I am having two tables (student and marks) like below screen:

**STUDENT TABLE:**

[image]

**MARKS TABLE:**

[image]

**QUERY:**

[image]

```
select s.*, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
    CASE WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science' else '' END
AS Remark,

CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
from marks as m
join student as s
on m.st_id = s.st_id
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** Column Remark will create once and final remark will be in siggle column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax issue in your query. Try using this.

If you want to show only one remark.

```
select s.*, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
    CASE WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math' 
    WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English' 
    WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science'
    WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi'
    WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science' else '' END
AS Remark,

CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
from marks as m
join student as s
on m.st_id = s.st_id
```

Otherwise if you want to combine all of the remark in column then use `concat`. Since there are multiple subject marks.

```
select s.*, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
   Concat( CASE WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science' else '' END
)
AS Remark, 
CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
from marks as m
join student as s
on m.st_id = s.st_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
select s.*, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
  trim(trailing ',' from  concat(
    CASE WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math,' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English,' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science,' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi,' else '' END,
    CASE WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science,' else '' END
  )) AS Remark,
CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
from marks as m
join student as s
on m.st_id = s.st_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using group_concat for remark  based on subquery

```
  select s.*, t.Total, group_concat(t.remark), t.result  
  from  join student as s 
  INNER JOIN  (
    select s.st_id, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
        CASE WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math' else '' END,
        CASE WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English' else '' END,
        CASE WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science' else '' END,
        CASE WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi' else '' END,
        CASE WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science' else '' END
    AS Remark,

    CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
    from marks as m
    join student as s
    on m.st_id = s.st_id

    ) t  on t.st_id = s.st_id
  GROUP BY s.st_id
```

Comment: `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 21
'group_concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near 't'.` showing this error while runnig your code

Comment: which db you are using ??? answer  updated ..removing wrong space after t.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one like in single case

```
 select s.*, m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science as Total,
        CASE
     WHEN m.math < 30 THEN 'Fail in Math'
        WHEN m.English < 30 THEN 'Fail in English'
         WHEN m.science < 30 THEN 'Fail in science'  
         WHEN m.Hindi < 30 THEN 'Fail in Hindi' 
        WHEN m.s_science < 30 THEN 'Fail in s_science' 
     END
    AS Remark,
    CASE WHEN (m.math+m.English+m.science+m.hindi+m.s_science) < 150 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' END AS Result
    from marks as m
    join student as s
    on m.st_id = s.st_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should maybe just be a remark in the comments section to your request, but is too long for a comment anyway ...

It would probably be better to change the database design to three tables:

- student (student_id, name, ...)
- class (class_id, name, ...)
- student_class (student_id, class_id, mark)

Thus you wouldn't have to know about specific subjects in your queries and you wouldn't have to alter all your queries everytime you remove or add a subject.

```
select *
from student
join
(
  select
    sc.student_id,
    sum(sc.mark) as total,
    group_concat(case when sc.mark < 30 then c.name end
                 order by c.name separator ', ') as failed_classes,
    sum(sc.mark) < 150 as failed
  from student_class sc
  join class c on c.class_id = sc.class_id
  group by sc.student_id
) evaluated using (student_id)
order by student_id;
```